Should footer socials be updated?
The current socials

Should the footer be updated to be X instead of Twitter? The URL remains twitter.com and media usually refers to "X, formerly known as Twitter", but they've technically re-branded to be X.
Should Threads social be added (https://www.threads.net/@thestackoverflow)? You have Twitter/X
Should Youtube be added (https://www.youtube.com/c/StackOverflowOfficial)? You have Instagram
As other footer menus are vertical maybe a SOCIAL with various links like:


Twitter or Xuuitter or X, that is the question.

Or perhaps those links should just all go away?
